# How to disable a button after a click discord.js v13

Tags: discord.js, discord-buttons

im trying to make the "Elevate To Management" button disable after someone has clicked it so that people dont spam ping the role by spamming the button.

```
    const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({time: 1000 });



                const row = new MessageActionRow()
                    .addComponents(
                        new MessageButton()
                            .setCustomId('supportticket_close')
                            .setLabel('Close Ticket')
                            .setStyle("DANGER")
                            .setEmoji(''),

                            new MessageButton()
                            .setCustomId('supportticket_elevate')
                            .setLabel('Elevate To Management')
                            .setStyle("SECONDARY")
                            .setEmoji('⬆️')
                            
                    );
                    if (channel) await channel.send({ content: interaction.user.toString(), embeds: [embed], components: [row] });

collector.on('collect', async interaction => {
    if (interaction.customId === 'supportticket_elevate') {
        row.components[1].setDisabled(true) //disables but_1
        interaction.editReply({ components: [row] });
    }})
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem, exactly? Are you recieving the "Interaction failed" dialog? If yes, try increasing the collector's time. Also try doing `interaction.update()` instead of `interaction.editReply()`.

Comment: Hello, it now sends the message I want it to send however still goes to "This interaction failed" when disabling the button

Comment: @ErikHallowell just change `editReply` to `update`